# Prop checked checkbox for selected row(s)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, selected, prop

On my table clicking the row will highlight it, and should also check the corresponding checkbox. Furthermore if the checkall checkbox is checked, all rows should be highlighted. If the checks remove, the highlights should be removed. I cannot give ids and would like to do this dynamically with .find() or .closest() or something similar. Any ideas? Thanks in advance! http://jsfiddle.net/7vLdxddr/3/

**jQuery**

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('selected');
                }
                else {
                    $('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                }

});

$("input[type=checkbox].checkall").on("click", function () {
        $(this).parents('.table:eq(0)').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an instance of `this` (which refers to the row clicked on) and `find`

```
$(this).find(":checkbox").prop("checked", true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2wpmxdp0/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use the checked property to add and remove class.

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $rowCheckbox = $this.find(":checkbox");
    // Add and remove class based on the class on the row
    // You can always use this as the event is bound to the 
    // row which is clicked. So can use the this context
    if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
        $this.removeClass('selected');
        // Uncheck the checkbox if already selected
        $rowCheckbox.prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        $this.addClass('selected');
        $rowCheckbox.prop('checked', true);
    }
});

// No need to use the checkbox selector again
// You have already added the class to it
$(".checkall").on("click", function (e) {
    // To make sure the row event is not fired
    // due to event bubbling
    e.stopPropagation();
    var isChecked = this.checked,
        $table = $(this).parents('.table:eq(0)'),
        $rows = $table.find('tr');
    $table.find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', isChecked);
    this.checked ? $rows.addClass('selected') : $rows.removeClass('selected');
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vLdxddr/6/)**